# getFile() not working while running spring boot jar

Tags: java, jar, spring-boot

I am getting FileNotFoundException."java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:jsonProject/build/libs/library.jar!/state/hierarchy.json (No such file or directory)"

```
DefaultResourceLoader defaultResourceLoader=new DefaultResourceLoader();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(defaultResourceLoader.getResource("state/hierarchy.json").getURL().getFile()));
```

The file is present in jar in folder /state/hierarchy.json.
I am trying to run us java -jar library.jar.
How can I get the file inside jar?

I have tried using this too.

```
ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("state/hierarchy.json");
FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(new File(classPathResource.getURL().getFile()));
```

Comment: I have tried this , but this also did not work

Comment: A file in a jar isn't a file you can access like that. a `File` has to be a resource directly on the file system not inside an archive.

Comment: so how I can write in that file inside jar?

Comment: @user3142222 You cannot. You can eventually read a file in the jar but not write it.

Comment: @user3142222 If you need to do some temporary edits on it, you can still copy it to a temp `File` then edit the temp `File`.

Comment: ok thanks @arnaud ,I want to write to same file .I think I have to convert it to war then instead of deployable jar.

Comment: @user3142222 jar, war... it will still be a zip file. You cannot write files in a zip file.

Comment: If you want to edit some data, either you keep an environment variable which points to a file or you use a database.